# Need to convert strint to int quickly python

Tags: python, time, pyautogui

I have a program that is supposed to take joystick position readings from an arduino (over serial), and translate them to mouse movements on my computer.

There is only one problem with this...
The string to integer conversion is way too slow, and it takes forever for the movements to register.
 I need either a faster way to convert a string to an integer value, or a way to skip the conversion altogether.

This is my current code:

```
import serial
import pyautogui
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    decoded_bytes = ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8")
    pos = decoded_bytes.split(':')
    xpos = int(pos[0])
    ypos = int(pos[1])
    print("x:", xpos, " y:", ypos)
    pyautogui.move(xpos, ypos)
```

Note: Output from arduino has **3** values:
0:0:0
First number: x
Second number: y
Third number: joystick button

Comment: Why not remove time.sleep()?

Comment: The `sleep()` and `ser.readline()` and `print(...)` statements are likely much more expensive than the int() statements.

Comment: The print statement is just for debugging, but the sleep() statement is to avoid a bug that kept crashing the program, and the ser.readline() statement is critical, as it reads the data from the arduino.

Comment: Are you sure the string to integer conversion is actually the bottleneck? How have you verified this?

Comment: I have verified this by taking out peices of code, and the main bottleneck is the string to integer conversion, and the other big one is the time.sleep() statement, but that is supposed to slow down the code a very small amount, to avoid serial communication bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work? This way you can read more than one line of input for each time you call `move()`. Some lines of input will be ignored, but that seems necessary if you're getting input faster than you can use it.

```py
import serial
import pyautogui
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
while True:
    time_to_move = time.time() + 0.001
    while True:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        if time.time() >= time_to_move:
            break
    x_bytes, y_bytes = ser_bytes[:-2].split(b':')
    x, y = int(x_bytes), int(y_bytes)
    pyautogui.move(x, y)
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it gives me the following error:  
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).
Is there a way to modify this for 3 values?

Comment: Then change `x_bytes, y_bytes = ...` to  `x_bytes, y_bytes, *_ = ...`

Comment: Or any other number of small fixes, like doing `split = ser_bytes[:-2].split(b':')` then `x = int(split[0])` and `y = int(split[0])`